# NoClassDefFoundError running method in war file caused by InvokedynamicClassLoader?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war, tomcat8

I'm working on a java 8 backend providing a rest api that is built with its dependency (another project required for the first projects execution - let us call it **Project B**) in a war file which is deployed on a tomcat 8. This **Project B** uses the invokedynamic package that can be found [here](http://www.reflection.uniovi.es/invokedynamic/doc/es/uniovi/reflection/invokedynamic/package-summary.html).

The execution of multiple methods throws an `NoClassDefFoundError`. A excerpt of the stack trace looks like this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: es/uniovi/reflection/invokedynamic/interfaces/Callable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at es.uniovi.reflection.invokedynamic.codegen.InvokedynamicClassLoader.register(InvokedynamicClassLoader.java:36)
    at es.uniovi.reflection.invokedynamic.codegen.ClassGenerator.getInstance(ClassGenerator.java:107)
    at es.uniovi.reflection.invokedynamic.MemberBSClass.getInstance(MemberBSClass.java:83)
    at es.uniovi.reflection.invokedynamic.MemberBSClass.getCallable(MemberBSClass.java:44)
    at es.uniovi.reflection.invokedynamic.ProxyFactory.getInvokedynamicCallable(ProxyFactory.java:773)
    at es.uniovi.reflection.invokedynamic.ProxyFactory.generateInvokeDynamicCallable(ProxyFactory.java:91)
```

The error causing class can be found [here](http://www.reflection.uniovi.es/invokedynamic/doc/es/uniovi/reflection/invokedynamic/interfaces/class-use/Callable.html).

**It is important to know** that another project, using this **Project B** as a dependency too, runs locally without any trouble (not a web application and contains a simple main call). That is the reason why i think that the deployment or execution does not work properly or missed something but i couldn't figure out the actual problem.

My war file contains the "missing" class:

```
WEB-INF/classes/es/uniovi/reflection/invokedynamic/interfaces/Callable.class
```

Its overall structure of this file looks like the following:

```
- error
    - some error files
- META-INF
    - MANIFEST.MF
- WEB-INF
    - classes
         - de. ... -> the backend project
         - es / uniovi ... -> dependency of Project B
         - net. ... -> the dependent project
    - lib
    - spring
    - web-dev.xml
    - web.xml
```

Is it possible that the `InvokedynamicClassLoader` causes the problem and is not executable running inside a tomcat? The method is called in this way:

```
Class<T> c = (Class<T>) InvokedynamicClassLoader.getClassLoader().register(className, code);
```

where `className` outputs something like

```
es/uniovi/reflection/invokedynamic/Callable1
```

Thanks for any suggestion due to the fact that i'm pretty new to java.

Comment: Your link in the sentence _"The error causing class can be found here."_ doesn't work for me  - can you check it?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Seems like the site is sometimes down. As a alternative i will link you to a github project that uses this library. [You can find the code here.](https://github.com/nguonly/lyrt/tree/master/lyrt-dep/src/main/java/es/uniovi/reflection/invokedynamic)

Comment: How do you build your war? What are the differences between the war you run locally and the one you deploy? Is the build process different?

Comment: I does not build the other (running) project as a war file. I just run it locally using its main function and in this case it works.

Comment: So how then you build the one that doesn't work? Why do you deploy it to tomcat if it has executable class (main class)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have two projects: one project (providing a web application) that is deployed using tomcat (and does not contain a main class) and another simple demo project with a main class (just to verify that the actual import of the dependency works).

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` Means that the class could not be initialized. It can be some static code error, linkage error or one of its dependencies is not on the classpath.  Compare the jars on lib with the lib from the project that is working.

Comment: How the invokedynamic package classes ended up in WEB-INF/classes/ folder? Are you using the dependency as a jar or copy-pasted the java files to your project? Did you compared the classpaths of war and main class project?

Comment: I had similar problem with my project. This framework called jhades(http://jhades.github.io/) helped me resolve it. All you have to include the jar and print the dependencies in your main program and compare it with the web application.

Comment: I agree with @OleksandrShpota: Are there any more details you can give us about the build setup? Are there any warnings that seem to be (even just remotely) related to duplicate classes after a shading process etc.?